# How to setup endless testing with Protractor with SauceLabs?

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, saucelabs, end-to-end

I have a webserver with protractor tests on it, i want to setup endless testing with saucelabs.
They say just add sauceLabs user and key to the `conf.js` file of protractor.

Should I use cron or something else to make it endless testing loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something you should not solve on the protractor level.

Use [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) or other continuous integration servers, or simply schedule it in cron.